# How to use the latest Dart unstable in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dart

Is it possible to use the latest Dart unstable in a docker container, if so how to specify it in the Dockerfile?

Comment: What version do you mean with unstable? Dev-channel or bleeding edge?

Comment: have a look at https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=dart&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0 and more specifically at https://hub.docker.com/r/google/dart/, this will give you hints about how to build the latest Dart unstable

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yeah, I want to use the latest dev-channel version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's documented here [Using apt-get](https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/linux.html#install-with-apt-get) (Setting up for the dev channel)

With a `Dockerfile` like

```
FROM google/debian:wheezy

ENV DART_VERSION 1.14.0-dev.1.0    

RUN \
  apt-get -q update && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q \
    apt-transport-https \
    apt-utils \
    apt-show-versions \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git 

RUN \
  curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
  curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_unstable.list > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_unstable.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-cache policy dart && \
  apt-get install dart=$DART_VERSION-1 && \
  apt-show-versions dart && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  ln -s /usr/lib/dart /usr/lib/dart/bin/dart-sdk
```

Dart `1.14.0-dev.1.0` is installed. The line `apt-show-versions dart && \` prints the available Dart versions in the build output (just for information purposes - can be removed).